# I am getting this error while running my app

Tags: java, gradle, networking, download, artifacts

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.
     Required by:
         project :app
 >Could not get resource 'https://storage.flutter-io.c/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420/x86_debug-1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.pom'.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://storage.flutter-io.c/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420/x86_debug-1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.pom'.
           [text](https://stackoverflow.com)> storage.flutter-io.c
```

> Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Could not resolve io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.
> Could not get resource 'https://storage.flutter-io.c/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://storage.flutter-io.c/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420.pom'.
> storage.flutter-io.c

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.

[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.

> I think problem is there

Comment: What is the problem here, please provide problem statement in the begging of your post

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's failing to get your resources:

> `Could not HEAD '...`

Looking at your error messages, though, it's trying to go to an invalid domain name:

> `https://storage.flutter-io.c/...`

`storage.flutter-io.c` is not a valid domain name.  This leads one to assume that you have mis-configured something elsewhere in your Gradle file.

Please either check your `build.gradle` or post it here for further investigation.